# Making a scrollable div without knowing the available height of the container

Tags: html, css

Disclaimer: I'm not the most experienced person when it comes to HTML, so this may be an obvious fix.

Here's my predicament: I'm working on a web page designed for smartphones and tablets, so the dimensions of the screen varies a lot. I have a `div` on the right side of my page which has a width of 60% and a height of 85%. Inside this there is a square image with `width: 100%` and another `div` with a few buttons that I would like to make scrollable. NOTE: I do not want to have the outermost of these two `div`s be scrollable, only the innermost one.

Because of this setup I can't know for sure where on the page the inner `div` begins, but I do know where it ends.

I looked through some old questions but I wasn't able to find anything too similar, but I did find a question where someone knows the size of the outermost `div` in a simplified version of the problem. I adapted the simplified HTML so that it represents my problem.

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s9Zfx/8/

Basically, I need to make it so that everything stays inside the blue box, the green box stays as is, and the red box is scrollable and contains the yellow box.

Thanks.

Comment: First of all please avoid using inline styles. it makes your code unreadable. [Why Use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Why_use_CSS). Second thing - the html you shared doesn't matches  your description. Third - "but I do know where it ends." so where does it end..?

Comment: I was in a similar situation a while ago and never really found the most elegant way to do this, so I am very interested in the solution you come to.

Comment: @zazvorniki look at my updated answer

Comment: new update for the answer

Comment: I have made an update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done with some row of jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/s9Zfx/9/

```
    <body>

<div id="div1">
    <div id="image-container">
        <img src=""></img>
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
        <div id="div3">
            <p>some scrollable</p>
            <p>content here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

css

```
    div{ display: table-cell;float:left;}
#div1 {
    height: 500px;
    width: 400px;
    border:5px solid blue;

}
#div2 {
    overflow:auto;
    border:5px solid red;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
#div3 {
   height:1000px;
   border:5px solid yellow;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width:100%;
}
#image-container {

    width: 100%;
    border:5px solid green;
}
```

jquery

```
var result1 = $("#image-container").height();

var result2 = $("#div1").height();

 $("#div2").height(result2-result1);
```

or if you want all in one line

```
$("#div2").height($("#div1").height() - $("#image-container").height());
```

without jquery I think it's impossible. Hope this solution may help you

Comment: Sorry, let me change the jsfiddle so that it more accurately describes the question I'm asking. The problem is that I don't know the height of div2, so I can't assume that it is 500px.

Comment: based on what content should div2 scroll?? wich is the max-height? can you post an image of what do you want?

Comment: If you look at the new example, I'm trying to find a way to have the red box contain yellow (scrollable, because the yellow box is so big), but I want the red box to begin where the green box ends and end where the blue box ends.

Comment: I can't just do that, which is why this is an annoying problem. I have to account for varying screen sizes

Comment: Sorry, maybe it wasn't clear in my description, and the example didn't really include this, but in my actual implementation I have no idea what the height of the image is because the image size is based on the length, and the aspect ratios vary between devices. I don't know what the height of the image is at all.